# Combination of Interval of Convergence

Tags: calculus

If given the Series A has an Interval of Convergence of [-4,8) and Series B has Interval of Convergence of (2,12] , is it fair to conclude the if we consider series A+B that its Interval of convergence would be (2,8)? I need some confirmation on this please. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. Suppose that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ converges for $-4 \leq x < 8$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ converges for $2 < x \leq 12$ . Then ofcourse, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n x^n + \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ converges for $x \in$ (2,8) since both series converge for all $x$ in this interval and therefore, their sum converges. Now suppose $x$ is not in $(2,8)$, i.e. 8 < $x \leq 12$. Then the sum $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n x^n + \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ diverges since the first series diverges. We get similar arguments for all the other possibilities of $x \notin (2,8)$.